# Express router - :id?

Tags: node.js, express

Real simple question guys: I see a lot of books/code snippets use the following syntax in the router:

```
app.use('/todos/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
  next();
});
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the route here... will it route '/todos/anything'? and then grab the 'anything' and treat is at variable ID? how do I use that variable? I'm sure this is a quick answer, I just haven't seen this syntax before.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is an express middleware.

In this case, yes, it will route `/todos/anything`, and then `req.params.id` will be set to `'anything'`

Answer (score 24):

On your code, that is for express framework middleware, if you want to get any id in the server code using that route, you will get that id by `req.params.id`.

```
app.use('/todos/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Id:', req.params.id);
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Route path: /student/:studentID/books/:bookId
Request URL: http://localhost:xxxx/student/34/books/2424
req.params: { "studentID": "34", "bookId": "2424" }

app.get('/student/:studentID/books/:bookId', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.params);
});
```

Similarly for your code:

```
Route path: /todos/:id
Request URL: http://localhost:xxxx/todos/36
req.params: { "id": "36" }

app.use('/todos/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Id:', req.params.id);
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in your example youl get `req.params.id` set to 'anything'

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but the question mark in your question made me think of something that hasn't been touched upon.

If your route had a question mark after the id like so: '/todos/:id?', id would be an optional parameter, meaning you could do a getAll() if id was omitted (and therefore undefined).

Answer (score 0):

This is called **Path params** and it's used to identify a specific resource.

and as all answer how to get the value of the path params

```
app.use('/todos/:id', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Request Id:', req.params.id); // 'anything'
});
```

read more about params type
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/