# Nodejs + Express: How to get an element which made an HTTP GET request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get-request

I am making a front using Express. I have a table where each row has a link that makes a GET request, so that the back-end (done with node.js) returns a file corresponding to that row.
All links make the url GET request like `"/documents/table/file"`.
What I intend to do is for my express server to be able to know which link of what row makes the GET request with the `req` field of it in order to be able to return the corresponding requested file.

The request is being handled in my express server as follows:

```
router.get('/documents/table/file', async (req, res) =>{
  //Get which element made the get petition
});
```

As I said before, I intend to know what link from which row of the table performs a request using the `req` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the information about the **row**/item that makes the `GET` request, that is a must.

Now with `Express` there are a couple of ways to do this: [**`Express routing`**](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters).

**1. Defining route params:** [req.params](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)

`GET` Request: `/documents/table/file/345` (345 is the row identifier `name or id` etc)

At nodejs express end:

```
router.get("/documents/table/file/:id", (req, res) => {
  /*request parameter with this kind of route sits in req.params*/
  console.log(req.params);
  const requestedId = req.params.id;
});
```

**2. Sending as query string parameters:** [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

`GET` Request: `/documents/table/file?id=345`

At nodejs express end:

```
router.get("/documents/table/file/", (req, res) => {
  /*request parameter with this kind of route sits in req.query*/
  console.log(req.query);
  const requestedId = req.query.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The short version is: you can't know this.

The way this is normally handled that if a request is needed for a specific item (or row in a table), you need to add some relevant information to the url that can identify it yourself.

So if it's a `GET` request for `/foo/get-file`, and every 'file' has some kind of unique id, you might want to change your url to `/foo/get-file/123` or `/foo/get-file?id=123`

Comment: Thanks for answering.  But how do you handle it on your node.js server?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to access specific file using `get` command? If so, here's an answer - [Express router - :id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095126/express-router-id).

More precisely, you write something like `router.get('/documents/table/file/:id)`, and this `:id` is available in `req.params` object.